# By mistake renamed Android project in Eclipse

Tags: android

I renamed my android project name in directory.But it gave some error. So i renamed back to original name.Now it doesnot work. What is the solution.
Can you please help.This was my first android project.

Comment: eclipse? intellij? studio?

Comment: What error message do you get from Eclipse?

Comment: Whats the new error (I mean after you renamed it back to the original name)? If you are using eclipse IDE for development then look for a tab called "problems" in the bottom panel. Try googling the problem pertaining to your project.

Comment: Look at the logcat view in the DDMS perspective (Window -> Open Perspective menu -> select DDMS). The logcat will show you the reason why the application was closed. It should be some trivial error. But you can also copy it here. However, if this was a first project, you should rather start a new one and copy the business logic. It's better than fighting with the development environment.

Comment: I agree but this is a big project.Almost 10 classes and many xml files.Help

Comment: Class not find exception.

Comment: You'd spend like 20 minutes setting it up again and correcting it can take anything from a few minutes to hours. I'd rather restart...

Comment: Okay.. :( :( :( :( :9

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a version control system. Try a rename and a complete rebuild.

Comment: Using a VCS now won't solve his problem. It will only help in the future.

Comment: Eclipse has local history by default. Try Replace with -> Local History or Restore from local history. It's a great tool. But in this case it would probably just mess up the internals.

Comment: Yes, I know. But unfortunatly this is the common way to learn such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

**Try: Right click on project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties.**

**Also try Project -> Clean...**

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
            <name>fooo</name>
```

1. Close eclipse
2. Go to the folder your project is in. (explorer or finder)
3. find the .project file and open in a text editor
4. edit the project name tag (where you see fooo above in project description > name tag)
5. close .project file
6. rename the folder to whatever you replaced "fooo"
7. reopen eclipse.

Comment: where is project name tag?

Comment: in the .project file is in the folder where your project is located on the filesystem

Answer (score 0):

If you have renamed your project in workspace and your project shows you error

Do these things
1) Rename the project again, the previous one
2) Go to project tab(in menu bar) > clean.

It will fix your project error.

SomeHow it still not work Do one more thing:

1) Copy The renamed project from workspace to any other location.
2) Delete the existing project which you renamed it from eclipse.
3) Import the project by following these steps

File>import>Android> Existing android project into workspace> Browse your project where you have just copied >dont forget to tick the checkbox (Copy projects into workspace) >finish

It will surely sort out your problem.